HLSL compute shader performance
I use two compute shaders written in HLSL:

The first calculates data and writes it to an intermediate buffer;
The second reads data from intermediate buffer, performs additional calculations and writes resulted data into two other buffers.

I measured the timing of both shaders:

The first was 2.2 ms
The second was 6.5 ms

As the timing of the second shader was higher than expected, I've experimented with moving writing operations from the second shader to the first.
When I moved one of the writing operations which doesn't require any preliminary data calculations from the second shader to the first shader - the timing of the first shader remained the same (2.2 ms) and the timing of the second shader reduced from 6.5 ms to 1.2 ms.
I'd like to understand the reason of this reduction.
And in non-optimized variants data to OutIndexBuffer is written in the second shader.
The target device where the measures were performed is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER
So, my question is - what could be the reason of the fact that two writing operations put in different shaders work much faster than in single one?
The code of the optimized variants of the shaders:
RWByteAddressBuffer     OutVertexBuffer         : register(u0);

RWByteAddressBuffer     OutIndexBuffer          : register(u1);

RWStructuredBuffer<QuadGeometry> quadGeometryBuffer : register(u2);


[numthreads(64, 1, 1)]
void HeightfieldConverterCS1( uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID )
{
    int indexX = DTid.x;
    if (indexX > nCountLat)
        return;

    int indexY = DTid.y;

    QuadGeometry quadGeom;

    ComputeQuadGeom2(indexX, indexY, quadGeom);

    uint index = indexFlattened(indexX, indexY);
    quadGeometryBuffer[index] = quadGeom;

    //запись индексов в буфер в первом шейдере, а не во втором, дает выигрыш по производительности
    //запись производится во всех квадратах кроме граничных
    if (indexX == 0 || indexY == 0 || indexX == nCountLat || indexY == nCountLon)
        return;

    indexX = indexX - 1;
    indexY = indexY - 1;

    uint nStartIndex = ( indexY * ( nCountLat - 1 ) + indexX ) * 6;

    OutIndexBuffer.Store( nStartIndex * 4, nStartIndex + 0 );
    OutIndexBuffer.Store( ( nStartIndex + 1 ) * 4, nStartIndex + 2 );
    OutIndexBuffer.Store( ( nStartIndex + 2 ) * 4, nStartIndex + 1 );

    OutIndexBuffer.Store( ( nStartIndex + 3 ) * 4, nStartIndex + 3 );
    OutIndexBuffer.Store( ( nStartIndex + 4 ) * 4, nStartIndex + 5 );
    OutIndexBuffer.Store( ( nStartIndex + 5 ) * 4, nStartIndex + 4 );
}



[numthreads(64, 1, 1)]
void HeightfieldConverterCS2( uint3 DTid : SV_DispatchThreadID )
{
    int iQuadLat = DTid.x;
    if (iQuadLat > nCountLat - 2)
        return;

    int iQuadLon = DTid.y;

    int indexX = iQuadLat + 1;
    int indexY = iQuadLon + 1;

    Vertices outData;
    ComputeQuadOutputData( indexX, indexY, outData );

    uint nStartIndex = ( iQuadLon * ( nCountLat - 1 ) + iQuadLat ) * 6;
    uint VERTEX_SIZE = 44;

    Vertex outVertex;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
    {
        uint nVertexStartIndex = nStartIndex + i;

        outVertex = outData.vertices[i];

        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE, asuint(outVertex.pos.x));
        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 4, asuint(outVertex.pos.y));
        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 8, asuint(outVertex.pos.z));

        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 12, asuint(outVertex.normal.x));
        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 16, asuint(outVertex.normal.y));
        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 20, asuint(outVertex.normal.z));

        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 24, asuint(outVertex.tex.x));
        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 28, asuint(outVertex.tex.y));

        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 32, asuint(outVertex.tangent.x));
        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 36, asuint(outVertex.tangent.y));
        OutVertexBuffer.Store(nVertexStartIndex * VERTEX_SIZE + 40, asuint(outVertex.tangent.z));
    }
}


We cannot answer this question without the code of the shader nor any advanced profiling information (nor even the target device). We can only make wild guess. Please edit the post to add such informations. Are the results actually valid? A wild guess could be cache trashing in the second shader...
